# How to reset jQuery toggled classes applied throughout the page? (AngularProject)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

The below CSS is applied on click of link available at one element:

```
<a class="vehicleinfo avai-vehicle-info-anc-tag" ng-click="vehicleInfo($event)">Vehicle Info 
    <span class="s-icon red-down-arrow"> </span>
</a>

$scope.vehicleInfo = function(event) {
    var el = jQuery(event.currentTarget),
    featuredcarbox = el.closest(".avilablecar.available-car-box");
    featuredcarbox.find(".avlcarimagetab img").toggleClass("slide-left");
    featuredcarbox.toggleClass("bg-grey");
    el.toggleClass("icon-remove");
    featuredcarbox.find(".available-car-fac").toggleClass("hidden");
}
```

I want to remove all the above toggled classes applied at each element (vehicle) on calling one function.

How can I achieve??

Comment: First of all, you have a few typos in your strings.

Comment: Have you tried removeClass("") ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

too simple.....i think. if you need to remove toggled classes just replace toggleClass to removeClass. as i show in new function/

```
$scope.vehicleClassRessetInfo = function(event) {
    var el = jQuery(event.currentTarget),
    featuredcarbox = el.closest(".avilablecar.available-car-box");
    featuredcarbox.find(".avlcarimagetab img").removeClass("slide-left");
    featuredcarbox.removeClass("bg-grey");
    el.removeClass("icon-remove");
    featuredcarbox.find(".available-car-fac").removeClass("hidden");
}
```

Comment: what to pass in event? I am clicking some other button in same page. @Vladimir Ch

Comment: use on  <a class="vehicleClassRessetInfo" ng-click="vehicleClassRessetInfo($event)">reset class</a>

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for ng-class with a ternary operator. Ng-class works like this:

`<div ng-class="(foo == 1) ? 'classes if-true' : 'classifFalse'"`

The "(foo == 1)" part can be an expression, an evaluated function, or a variable from the controller.

I don't have enough to work with to put it in a fiddle I don't think, but here is what I would do...

HTML:

```
<a ng-class="(applyClassses == true) ? 'vehicleinfo avai-vehicle-info-anc-tag' : ''" ng-click="vehicleInfo($event)">Vehicle Info 
  <span class="s-icon red-down-arrow"></span>
</a>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.vehicleInfo = function() {
  if () {
    $scope.applyClasses = true;
  }
  else {
    $scope.applyClasses = false;
  }
}
```